# Bind dropdownlist to value already showing in ItemTemplate on gridview on edit

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have to bind my dropdownlist value to my edit template. Below is code behind for my dropdownlist.

```
 protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if this is our Blank Row being databound, if so make the row invisible
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        if (((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["CertificateNo"].ToString() == String.Empty) e.Row.Visible = false;
        //Check if is in edit mode
       if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList DropDownListStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownListStatus");
            //Bind status data to dropdownlist
            DropDownListStatus.DataTextField = "Status";
            DropDownListStatus.DataValueField = "Status";
            DropDownListStatus.DataSource = RetrieveStatus();
            DropDownListStatus.DataBind();
            DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            DropDownListStatus.SelectedValue = dr["Status"].ToString();
           }


    }
}

private DataTable RetrieveStatus()
{
    //fetch the connection string from web.config
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    //SQL statement to fetch entries from products
    string sql = @"Select distinct Status from cpd_certificates";
    DataTable dtStatus = new DataTable();
    //Open SQL Connection
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        //Initialize command object
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //Fill the result set
            adapter.Fill(dtStatus);
        }
    }
    return dtStatus;
}
```

The code above populates my dropdownlist. However when I click edit my dropdownlist is not populated.
Here is my dropdownlist code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
                                            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Status")%></ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListStatus" runat="server">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListStatus" runat="server" >

                                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at your code  shows that  you have an error in the order of assigning your values to the dropdownlist.First assign your datasource to your dropdownlist and then assign datavalue- field and datatext-field properties after the datasource assignment.

```
 DropDownListStatus.DataSource = RetrieveStatus();
 DropDownListStatus.DataTextField = "Status";
 DropDownListStatus.DataValueField = "Status";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Nothing wrong with the order. Just figured that my edit link  is the one thats wrong. When I click Edit the row to be editted is of previous page.